# How to loop audio through a pi for voice change effects?

Tags: audio, connectors

I want to put a raspberry pi as a voice changer (using sox) between a headset and a game console to add some authentic voice effects for video games.

The raspberry pi needs to loop the audio signal from the ps5 controller through the pi to the headset (unchanged), and loop the microphone signal from the headset through the pi (changed by sox) to the ps5 controller. See sketch.

I don't know  which hardware I need for the pi to get this up an running. I think the left connector on the pi (sketch) can be done by a usb soundcard, but for the right connector (sketch) I have no idea. Any idead how to solve this?

[image: sketch]

Comment: does the RPi have a microphone input?

Comment: the diagram is somewhat incorrect ... the PS5 controller R and L should be connected directly to the headset ... the RPi R and L outputs should go to PS5 microphone input

Comment: @jsotola: No the RPi does not have a mic input (at least not on board).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by buying a cheap usb sound card for the pi (5€) and two y-splitter cables. I connected the audio from the ps5 controller directly to the headset while looping the microphone singnal from the headset through the pi, by connecting the headset to the mic input of the soundcard and the audio output of the soundcard to the mic of the controller. See sketch. Then altered the microphone signal in the pi using sox.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The Raspberrypi has **NO** microphone input (or ANY analog capabilities).

If you want to do this on a Pi you will need some kind of audio module. There are a number available (most costing more than a Pi).

While it would be possible, the Pi is a poor choice for such a project.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you think of a better solution than using a pi?

Answer (score 2):

The pi has no analog audio, and only digital audio out.  I have also seen at least one pi hat that can add analog audio, but it was quite expensive.  Cheap USB sound cards are available (with wildly varying quality) and may be able to do this task.  Most of them have TRS plugs with separate plugs for line in and speaker out rather than the TRRS plugs you have shown, so you may need appropriate adapters/splitters.

If (as suggested in comments) you send the PS5 output directly to your headset, you can probably do this with a single USB sound card.  However, passing the audio through the pi both directions (using two usb sound cards) would allow you to mix your own distorted audio with the game audio so you can hear your distorted self.  Doing this would probably add a huge delay to the audio stream you hear, so this may be a bad idea.

As the pi has no native analog audio, it may not be the most suitable device.  There are websites (like armbian.com) that list other SBC's, you might be able to find one with at least one analog audio in/out, but I'd be surprised if you find one with two.